# c++: Trouble detecting ascension of numbers in an array

Tags: c++

I'm a novice to c++ programming and currently taking a class as an introduction to programming. I am currently working on a homework project where I input 10 integers and determine whether the numbers are in ascending order or not.

The issue I'm having is that the program always thinks there is a ascension, no matter the input provided. I figured the problem lies in the IsInOrder() function's for loop, however I can't figure out why exactly it isn't working or how to fix it.

Another potential problem is how to determine ascension for all values, for instance if my code worked I think it would count [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as an ascension, even though it's not.

I've tried searching online and have found a few similar assignment questions, but with no answer to these problems.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool IsInOrder (int numHold[]);

//This portion takes the numeral inputs and outputs the answer
int main()

{
int numHold[10];

bool status;

cout << "Welcome to the Ascension detector 5000" << endl;
cout << "This program will detect whether the numbers you input are in ascending   
order" << endl;
cout << "Isn't that neat?" << endl <<endl;

for (int i=0; i < 10;i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> numHold[i];
}
cout << endl;

for(int i=0;i < 10;i++)
{
    cout << numHold[i] << endl;
}

status = IsInOrder(numHold);

if (status == true)
{
    cout << "The numbers are in ascending order" << endl;
}
else
{
     cout << "The numbers are not in ascending order" << endl;
}



system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

//This function determines whether the inputs are in ascending order

 bool IsInOrder (int numHold[])
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
        if (numHold[i] < numHold [i++])
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
}
}
```

Appreciate any help in advance and sorry if the code isn't well formatted, the code wasn't copy/pasting well in to the code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `IsInOrder` Function, run for loop till `i<9` and remove else part and put `return true` outside the `for` loop.

Why `return true` outside the for loop?

Because return `true` only when you checked all the element, not every time. Take a look at your code you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `IsInOrder` routine doesn't check all the values in the array, it returns immediately after encountering two different numbers.

Also, if it would run through the entire array (i.e. when all the numbers would be the same), it would have checked 11 elements by the time it ended instead of 10, and it wouldn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsInOrder(int numHold[])
{
    bool inOrder = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (numHold[i] > numHold[i+1])
        {
            inOrder = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return inOrder;
}
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! Though I don't understand why this works compared to the one I input?

Comment: @user1887219 yours was wrong in multiple ways, for one the `return` statements that are executed after you check the first number end the function before checking any others. The other thing is that `if (numHold[i] < numHold [i++])` essentially means `if (numHold[i] < numHold [i]){i=i+1;` (not the exact order of evaluation but its the same result in your case). I Imagine you know what's wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `true` and `false` branches are the wrong way round.

Secondly (assuming `true`/`false` has been fixed), you conclude that the entire sequence is in the ascending order as soon as you've seen two numbers that are in order. That's not correct: you can't `return true` until you've examined *every pair*.

Lastly, the loop's terminal condition is off by one.

```
bool IsInOrder(int numHold[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (numHold[i] >= numHold[i+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```